Prince falls while ice-skating through fault of a commoner and she goes to jail
About 13 years ago I watched a children's movie (in English), but I've searched for it and can't find it, hope you can help.
The plot how I remember it:
A girl is ice-skating and the prince of the country joins here and then he falls. She gets blamed while it wasn't really her fault and she goes to jail. She is in the jail with a couple of others and they escape by pretending they were chained while the chains were actually loose. Then she meets the prince again and all is well.

How old was this movie (was it new when you saw it in 2001?), and do you remember anything about what the characters look like?

Apparently it was from 1996, and the plot was really all I could remember. Thanks for replying!

Sounds like the plot of The Ice Princess from 1996 with figure skater Katarina Witt. From IMDb:

This is another variation of the Cinderella story: the bright and beautiful Ella lives in the household of a lord since her mother died. She's unhappy because the lord's daughters treat her like their servant. The country is in problems, because the prince is a dreamer and doesn't realize that his chancellor abuses his power. When the day nears the prince is forced by law to find a wife, a celebration on a frozen lake is arranged. Ella manages to skate on the lake for him too, hiding her identity.

The prince falls on the skating rink and Ella is thrown in prison, but she later manages to escape it with the other child prisoners. This film is German, but maybe it was dubbed. Here's a clip:




Yes this is it! Must've been dubbed when I watched it, thanks a lot!
